# For loop in stat_function R

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot multiple logistic regressions using stat_function. I want to pass the values of the different compounds separatedly so I can obtain three different LR. I am able to do that specifying the name of the Compound by hand, but I want to do that automatically so I can apply it later to an unspecified uploaded file. Here's the script:

```
rm(list =ls())

dev.off()

require(nplr)
require(ggplot2)

data <- read.csv(multicell3.csv, header =TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

data["x"] <- log(data["x"])

data["y"] <- convertToProp(data["y"], T0 = NULL, Ctrl = NULL)

models <- nplr(x=data$x, y = data$y, npars = "all", useLog = FALSE)

B <- getPar(models)$params$bottom
TT <- getPar(models)$params$top
xmid <- getPar(models)$params$xmid
s <- getPar(models)$params$s
bb <- getPar(models)$params$scal

logistic <- function(x) { 
 (B+(TT-B)/(1+10^(bb*(xmid - x)))^s)
}

p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, colour = Compound)) + geom_point()

for (i in 1:unique(data$Compound)) {


 if (i<unique(data$Compound)){

  p1 <- p1 + stat_function(fun = logistic(i))
 }

 if (i == unique(data$Compound)){

  plot(p1)
 }

}
```

And the data I use:

```
Compound    x           y
Hurrycane   1.00E-08    1.226316143
Hurrycane   1.00E-07    0.931568763
Hurrycane   1.00E-06    0.527434482
Hurrycane   1.00E-05    0.342868146
Hurrycane   1.00E-04    0.077712851
Hurrycane   0.001      -0.188956597
Hurrycane   0.01       -0.10295328
Hurrycane   0.1        -0.066842356
MummyHunter 1.00E-08    0.82905986
MummyHunter 1.00E-07    1.186264371
MummyHunter 1.00E-06    1.049254029
MummyHunter 1.00E-05    0.846015133
MummyHunter 1.00E-04    0.628981497
MummyHunter 0.001       0.236252425
MummyHunter 0.01        0.136820743
MummyHunter 0.1         0.104911859
easyRider   1.00E-08    0.966133281
easyRider   1.00E-07    1.22745977
easyRider   1.00E-06    0.767577806
easyRider   1.00E-05    1.086589519
easyRider   1.00E-04    1.007547357
easyRider   0.001       0.930612619
easyRider   0.01        0.511694103
easyRider   0.1        -0.010537418
```

I read a lot of things about `for` loop, but mostly are about adding values to something while what I want is to tell the function which group of numbers should it use to calculate the parameters for the logistic regression. I think the problem is that I am not able to tell the parameters (B,TT,xmid...) whether to calculate the values from one compound or the other.